# Issue writing to a text or pdf file in DOT NET Core

Tags: .net-core

We have a dot net core app (2.1) which is being developed under VS 2017 on Windows 10. Locally it works as intended.

One feature is to write an text file to a folder that is not in the development directory.  That is, it is in some specific spot on my local hard drive. Say it's D:\Logfiles

The it is published to a Windows 2016 server on AWS. We have it running via IIS and the application works well except that when we try to write a text file to a folder outside of the application directory, it fails silently

I have tried assigning rights to this external folder in the way we did with regular dot net applications, but it will not write the text file.

How do we configure a dot net core app to link in another folder so the C# code can write to it?

Thanks,

Stephen

Comment: As what user is the IIS process running?  That's the user to which write permissions would need to be granted.

Answer (score 0):

You need to give permission to the App Pool from your application. Replace "DefaultAppPool" with your app pool name.

1. Right click on the desired folder and select "Properties"
2. Select the "Security" tab
3. Click the "Edit" and then "Add" button
4. Click the "Locations" button and make sure you select the local machine.
5. Enter "IIS AppPool\DefaultAppPool" in the "Enter the object names to select:" text box.
6. Click the "Check Names" button and click "OK".